# ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next

Tags: java, sql

Hi I have problem with this code as it seems to always return the SQL Exception. It was working for a few goes then stopped and came back with exception. so I'm not sure what's wrong.
I have tried to change the vld.close() to different places before so yeah. Thanks

```
PreparedStatement vld = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM carsharing.available(?,?,?,?)");
        vld.setString(1, carName);
        vld.setString(2, memberUser);
        vld.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(startTime.getTime()));
        vld.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(endTime.getTime()));
        System.out.println("test1");
        ResultSet rset = vld.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("test2");
        rset.next();
        int num = rset.getInt("num");
        boolean valid = rset.getBoolean("aval");
        vld.close();
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(valid);
```

Comment: yes. It was actually working before then stopped working...

Comment: what is your exception? Stack trace please.

Comment: SQL Exception : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.

Comment: if SQL is correct, can you explain what it does (sorry offtopic).

Comment: rset.next(); returns boolean, can you see what it returns? just put System.out.println(rset.next());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Verify SQL**

Can you verify first that the SQL is correct? It doesn't look correct to me. What you now try to execute is the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM carsharing.available(?,?,?,?)
```

If you want to limit the resultset by the given name, user and timestamps SQL should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM carsharing WHERE carNameField=? AND memberUserField=? AND tsField1=? AND tsField2=?
```

Where you would replace the Field names with the correct column names for your schema.

**2) Resultset navigation**

Then when you have your resultset after execution you can use first() to navigate to the first position and it also returns boolean so you can check if there even are results available. If you want more values fetched you'll need a loop.

```
//...
ResultSet rset = vld.executeQuery();
if( rset.first()){
   int num = rset.getInt("num");
   boolean valid = rset.getBoolean("aval");   
}
//...
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a SQL problem instead of Java

Answer (score 0):

U need to iterate the result set. U just can't as
    `rset.next();`
The code is

```
ResultSet rset = vld.executeQuery();
System.out.println("test2");
while(rset.next()) {
  int num = rset.getInt("num");
  boolean valid = rset.getBoolean("aval");
  System.out.println(num);
  System.out.println(valid);
}
vld.close();
```